Comparing our post scores with our peer sites
I adapted some Data Explorer queries to compare our post scores with our peers (questions and answers): see plots below.

I included posts created since 2019 (i.e., in 2019 or in 2020 up to the last Data Explorer update).

I chose non-English language sites which have accumulated 1000+ questions within this time frame.  Namely

Japanese.SE (4326 Qs; 5037 As),
German.SE (2333 Qs; 5235 As),
French.SE (2153 Qs; 4455 As),
Chinese.SE (1815 Qs; 4261 As),
Spanish.SE (1481 Qs; 2764 As), and
Latin.SE (1181 Qs; 1918 As).



These numbers are striking.  Either we're (a) failing to vote, or (b) voting appropriately but attracting un-vote-worthy ("meh") posts.  Or maybe a bit of both.
I repeat the plea... please Vote Early, Vote Often!
Both upvotes and downvotes are needed.  Please strive to make this a place where people want to contribute high-quality posts; we need to stop people thinking

pfft, it's not worth the effort of writing a high-quality post, it won't get upvoted anyway,

and get them thinking

wow, if I put in more effort, I'll get more upvotes.

Below are the plots.  We can see e.g. 29.81% of questions here have a score of 1, and 32.34% of answers here have a score of 1.


While I'm looking, there's some other statistics:

Number of 0-score questions here: 25.12%.  Our peers: ≤15.53% (next highest: Japanese.SE).
Number of 0-score answers here: 23.45%.  Our peers: ≤15.23% (next highest: Spanish.SE).

And with regards to badges (all time):
                     Question          Answer
                 Nice Good Great   Nice Good Great

   Japanese.SE   1910  180     4   2488  218     6   [21909 Qs]
   German.SE     1828  167     1   3432  373     2   [13588 Qs]
   French.SE      951   83     0   1378   95     0   [10241 Qs]
   Chinese.SE     376   32     1    606   23     0   [8240 Qs] <-----
   Spanish.SE     493   41     0    872   48     0   [7537 Qs]
   Latin.SE       628   33     0    650   32     1   [3732 Qs]

Again, we see we're significantly behind our peers.  (I previously compared some basic site statistics back in November 2019; it was just as alarming back then.)
